# Java delaying return of variable

Tags: java

How can I delay returning a varaible from a method in Java, or how should I do it if it is something unwanted to do?

Consider this:

```
public class Transaction {
    public int addInsert() {
        ...
        return insertId;
    }

    public boolean addUpdate() {
        ...
        return updateSuccesful;
    }

    public void commit() {
        /* Calls everything that is inserted via addInsert or addUpdate. */
    }
}
```

Now assume you use the code as:

```
Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
int insertedId = transaction.addInsert();
boolean updateSuccesful = transaction.addUpdate();
//insertId, updateSuccesful cannot be known yet

transaction.commit();
//now insertId, updateSuccesful should be filled in
```

So the return may only happen if `transaction.commit()` has been called.

Any thoughts?

Comment: How are you planning on returning both the `int` and `bool` from a void method?

Comment: My first thought, that I can not correctly understand what do you mean. Try to clarify your question.

Comment: Rather than delaying something (which is not likely possible in your scenario) work on your control flow....

Comment: @thatidiotguy The `transaction.addInsert()` and `transaction.addUpdate()` are the ones that will return something. But only after `transaction.commit()` has been called.

Comment: You want to return before commit ?

Comment: Even some temporary variable could be returned, and that variable could later be updated by `transaction.commit()` and then there would need to be some lock in place that prevents reading in the calling code. But I think that is ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're example looks like the Unit of Work Pattern: http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html
Which also shows the answer to your question.
You can't actually call method a, and have it's return value delayed until you call method b without getting into threading, and that's still going to be an overly complicated and very brittle solution to the problem.
Instead call method a, method b etc.  However don't actually do the work until the commit happens.  Then the commit returns, or you can call a getMethodAStatus() etc.

Comment: It makes sense, but it is kind of hard to design a `getXXX()` function, since return values may be a boolean and an integer mixed interchangebly and moreover the number if `add()` statements is only bounded by some finite number.

Comment: Make your "add" statements follow the Command Pattern.  Then add each command to your unit of work.  Then you can pull out and query each add.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this functionality by multithreading and making the threads that are running those two methods `.wait()` until the `commit()` method calls `.notify()` to let them know that they can finish.

However, a better way to structure this is to re-organize your your methods, perhaps by making commit return the `insertedID` and make it `return -1` if it is unsuccessful.  That way you can check the boolean by seeing if it is -1 or not, and you can read the ID by reading the return of commit.